# Why is my hover state in this memory tiles javascript project not working?

Tags: javascript, project, khan-academy

I am trying to add a hover state to this memory tiles project on Khan Academy. I believe I have inserted the correct code at the bottom to change to color of the tile, but when I test the code it only flashes the image that I want to show when hovered quickly, and then it disappears. It seems like some draw function is drawing over it every time the hover state tries to appear. Please help - i've been stuck on this for so long.

```
var Tile = function(x, y, face) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = 70;
    this.face = face;
    this.isFaceUp = false;
    this.isMatch = false;
};

Tile.prototype.draw = function() {
    fill(214, 247, 202);
    strokeWeight(2);
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.width, 10);
    if (this.isFaceUp) {
        image(this.face, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.width);
    } else {
        image(getImage("avatars/leaf-green"), this.x, this.y, this.width, this.width);
    }
};

Tile.prototype.isUnderMouse = function(x, y) {
    return x >= this.x && x <= this.x + this.width  &&
        y >= this.y && y <= this.y + this.width;
};

// Global config
var NUM_COLS = 5;
var NUM_ROWS = 4;

// Declare an array of all possible faces
var faces = [
    getImage("avatars/leafers-seed"),
    getImage("avatars/leafers-seedling"),
    getImage("avatars/leafers-sapling"),
    getImage("avatars/leafers-tree"),
    getImage("avatars/leafers-ultimate"),
    getImage("avatars/marcimus"),
    getImage("avatars/mr-pants"),
    getImage("avatars/mr-pink"),
    getImage("avatars/old-spice-man"),
    getImage("avatars/robot_female_1")
];

// Make an array which has 2 of each, then randomize it
var possibleFaces = faces.slice(0);
var selected = [];
for (var i = 0; i < (NUM_COLS * NUM_ROWS) / 2; i++) {
    // Randomly pick one from the array of remaining faces
    var randomInd = floor(random(possibleFaces.length));
    var face = possibleFaces[randomInd];
    // Push twice onto array
    selected.push(face);
    selected.push(face);
    // Remove from array
    possibleFaces.splice(randomInd, 1);
}

// Now shuffle the elements of that array
var shuffleArray = function(array) {
    var counter = array.length;

    // While there are elements in the array
    while (counter > 0) {
        // Pick a random index
        var ind = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
        // Decrease counter by 1
        counter--;
        // And swap the last element with it
        var temp = array[counter];
        array[counter] = array[ind];
        array[ind] = temp;
    }
};
shuffleArray(selected);

// Create the tiles
var tiles = [];
for (var i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < NUM_ROWS; j++) {
        var tileX = i * 78 + 10;
        var tileY = j * 78 + 40;
        var tileFace = selected.pop();
        tiles.push(new Tile(tileX, tileY, tileFace));
    }
}

background(255, 255, 255);

var numTries = 0;
var numMatches = 0;
var flippedTiles = [];
var delayStartFC = null;

mouseClicked = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
        var tile = tiles[i];
        if (tile.isUnderMouse(mouseX, mouseY)) {
            if (flippedTiles.length < 2 && !tile.isFaceUp) {
                tile.isFaceUp = true;
                flippedTiles.push(tile);
                if (flippedTiles.length === 2) {
                    numTries++;
                    if (flippedTiles[0].face === flippedTiles[1].face) {
                        flippedTiles[0].isMatch = true;
                        flippedTiles[1].isMatch = true;
                        flippedTiles.length = 0;
                        numMatches++;
                    }
                    delayStartFC = frameCount;
                }
            } 
            loop();
        }
    }
};

draw = function() {
    background(255, 255, 255);
    if (delayStartFC && (frameCount - delayStartFC) > 30) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
            var tile = tiles[i];
            if (!tile.isMatch) {
                tile.isFaceUp = false;
            }
        }
        flippedTiles = [];
        delayStartFC = null;
        noLoop();
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
        tiles[i].draw();
    }

    if (numMatches === tiles.length/2) {
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        textSize(20);
        text("You found them all in " + numTries + " tries!", 20, 375);

    }
};

noLoop();

Tile.prototype.hoverState = function() {
    fill(74, 122, 128);
    strokeWeight(2);
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.width, 10);
    image(getImage("avatars/leaf-yellow"), this.x, this.y, this.width, this.width);
    this.isFaceUp = false;
};

mouseMoved = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= tiles.length; i++) {
        if (tiles[i].isUnderMouse(mouseX, mouseY) && tiles[i].isFaceUp) {
            tiles[i].hoverState();
        } else if (tiles[i].isFaceUp) {
            tiles[i].drawFaceUp();
        } else {
            tiles[i].drawFaceDown();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you've looked into the `mouseover` event  ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event

Comment: Could you show the full code?

Comment: @JavascriptDev This is the full code - in khan academy everything is purely javascript, this project has no additional HTML or CSS or link to - everything is made with javascript

Comment: @Pogrindis I have looked into it, slightly confused on how to use it though. Everything in this course picked up really fast and it all is pretty confusing to me. I can read the code easily (it makes sense to me), but its pretty hard for me to piece it together from memory/logic.

Comment: But, first lines? Have you missed it when copying?

Comment: @JavascriptDev oops. Sorry first time posting on here - I fixed it

Comment: @JavascriptDev Any ideas on how to make this program work?